# Vega transformation sample

Tags: vega

This sample code from vega transformations is not working.

I am not getting the expected results.

Can you please help me run this example in the vega editor?

```
[
  {"foo": {"a": 5, "b": "abc"}, "bar": 0},
  {"foo": {"a": 6, "b": "def"}, "bar": 1},
  {"foo": {"a": 7, "b": "ghi"}, "bar": 2}
]
```

To extract the "bar" field along with the "a" and "b" sub-fields into new objects, use the transform:

```
{
  "type": "project",
  "fields": ["bar", "foo.a", "foo.b"],
  "as": ["bar", "a", "b"]
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
[
  {"bar":0, "a":5, "b":"abc"},
  {"bar":1, "a":6, "b":"def"},
  {"bar":2, "a":7, "b":"ghi"}
]
```

Comment: To me the output looks correct and works in the editor. Could you please describe the expected output (if the one you mentioned is not what you want)?

Comment: can you share you editor gist

Comment: Open the Data Viewer Panel: https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhAATJJhSoA2qHFIEcNCEVMANlpnEkehnAhpVIAGZs2aUEoEym2pEyggAvi6QAnNAAGH1Bbe1RHNAA2F21ZOGtvXwDUAEYQmzsHECUAdlj0MhgaJJAmfzQAJi8AXRlMPyRxCFs-BEtQTABPHC10HD82YTgoTGkbGjg9WQsVMoqZMMoURbtKVzqc2eV5gJkVspAa2pOgA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I used the very first sample in the [editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/) (the bar chart one) to demonstrate the transformation for you. Here is the modified code you can paste in the editor:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic bar chart example, with value labels shown upon mouse hover.",
  "width": 400,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,

  "data": [
    {
      "name": "table",
      "values": [
        {"foo": {"a": 5, "b": "abc"}, "bar": 0},
        {"foo": {"a": 6, "b": "def"}, "bar": 1},
        {"foo": {"a": 7, "b": "ghi"}, "bar": 2}
    ], 

    "transform": [
        {
          "type": "project",
          "fields": ["bar", "foo.a", "foo.b"],
          "as": ["bar", "a", "b"]
        }
      ]
    }    
  ],

  "signals": [
    {
      "name": "tooltip",
      "value": {},
      "on": [
        {"events": "rect:mouseover", "update": "datum"},
        {"events": "rect:mouseout",  "update": "{}"}
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "xscale",
      "type": "band",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "bar"},
      "range": "width",
      "padding": 0.05,
      "round": true
    },
    {
      "name": "yscale",
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "a"},
      "nice": true,
      "range": "height"
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
    { "orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale" },
    { "orient": "left", "scale": "yscale" }
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data":"table"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "bar"},
          "width": {"scale": "xscale", "band": 1},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "a"},
          "y2": {"scale": "yscale", "value": 0}
        },
        "update": {
          "fill": {"value": "steelblue"}
        },
        "hover": {
          "fill": {"value": "red"}
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "bottom"},
          "fill": {"value": "#333"}
        },
        "update": {
          "x": {"scale": "xscale", "signal": "tooltip.bar", "band": 0.5},
          "y": {"scale": "yscale", "signal": "tooltip.a", "offset": -2},
          "text": {"signal": "tooltip.b"},
          "fillOpacity": [
            {"test": "datum === tooltip", "value": 0},
            {"value": 1}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here would be the expected result:

[image]

As you can see in the data viewer of the editor, "bar" "a" and "b" have the correct values, and I have changed the bar chart so it uses those values to show the bars, the appropriate height, as well as the tooltip when you hover over a bar.